# Adding outlined text to small + large logos to look good

Tags: adobe-photoshop, logo, corel-paint-shop-pro

I'm trying to add some outlined text to a product logo. I've got paint shop pro which can produce outlined text, with a variable outline line width.

My images are 512x512, 114x114 and 57x57.

I also have access to an old version adobe photoshop v6.

I've finally picked two colours which work together.

However when I resize my large image it anti-aliases into a mess. I've tried the middle size with not much better results.

Also at the smaller size, looks very pixelated.

I figure there must be a technique to this.

Can anyone advise me what's the best approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First things first logos should be vector based to avoid anti aliasing problems. Since that does not seem to be an option for you try to adjust your image resolution in photoshop. When you create a new document the window that prompts for document size and name etc. has a standard resolution setting of 72. Adjust this to 300 and see if that helps you! Then use a font you like and apply a layer style of outline to the text.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using blending options (stroke, specifically) for the text? If so, you shouldn't have a problem resizing text + effect, except for the fact that you will need to re-adjust your Stroke after you do it.